# How to delete elements of and array by two attributes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in AngularJS like this:

```
var example = [ {id:'1',
                 read: false,
                 folder: 'inbox'},
                {id:'2',
                 read: true,
                 folder: 'inbox'},
                {id:'3',
                 read: true,
                 folder: 'trash'},
                 {id:'4',
                 read: false,
                 folder: 'trash'}];
```

And I need to delete any object that has the attributes `folder == 'trash'` and `read == true` **at the same time**.

So I tried to do it like this with [lodash](https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash):

```
example = lodash.filter(example, function(value, index) {
    return (value.folder !== 'trash') && (value.read !== true);
});
```

It should delete only the item **#3**, but it deletes **#3** and **#4**.

Obviously I'm not understanding how lodash.filter really works.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logical operator is not correct. set the condition to `folder == 'trash'` and `read == true` and the negate it.

```
example = lodash.filter(example, function(value) {
    return (value.folder == 'trash' && value.read == true) == false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes around 'true'. You want to keep all the elements where the folder is not 'trash' or the read property is not `true` so your logic would look like this

```
return (value.folder !== 'trash') || (value.read !== true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator !== is false. use == instead.

```
  return (value.folder == 'trash' && value.read == 'true') == false;
```